# How to handle the browser cache issue in Oracle JET web application

Tags: oracle, caching, web-applications, oracle-jet

I am facing the cache issue whenever I do a new deployment, changes are not reflecting automatically. Always I  have to go to the browser setting and clear the cache.
Is there a way to handle this issue automatically whenever I do the new deployment.

Answer (score 1):

```
requirejs.config({
// Path mappings for the logical module names
         paths: {
                'knockout': 'libs/knockout/knockout-3.4.0',
                'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min',
                'jqueryui-amd': 'libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.12.0',
                'promise': 'libs/es6-promise/es6-promise.min',
                'ojs': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/min',
                'ojL10n': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/ojL10n',
                'ojtranslations': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/resources',
                'signals': 'libs/js-signals/signals.min',
                'text': 'libs/require/text',
                'hammerjs': 'libs/hammer/hammer-2.0.8.min',
                'moment': 'libs/moment/moment.min',
                'ojdnd': 'libs/dnd-polyfill/dnd-polyfill-1.0.0.min',
                'customElements': 'libs/webcomponents/CustomElements'

              },
       waitSeconds: 0,
       // urlArgs will be appended at end of .js files 
       urlArgs: "v=1.33",
      // Shim configurations for modules that do not expose AMD
      shim: {
          'jquery': {
           exports: ['jQuery', '$']
           }
          },
     config: {
              ojL10n: {
              merge: {
              //'ojtranslations/nls/ojtranslations': 'resources/nls/menu'
                 }
               }
             }
    });
```

You can update version (by changing urlArgs parameter in configuration) every time you deploy new code, thus every time new JavaScript file will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This can always be a problem during development.  There are a couple of solutions.
1) Build into your app URL, a version string.  Every time you publish a new version, change that number and the browser will pull new files
2) Set the cache control values on your server so that it doesn't cache anything from your app directory
3) Just do what you're doing with clearing browser cache.  There are utilities that add a button on the browser bar to make it easier to get at.

I personally use the node http-server library to run my dev work and I use it's cache control arguments to make sure nothing is being cached.

http-server -c-1 -o

The above turns off caching and launches the browser from the current location (loading index.html if present)

Comment: can you please explore more how to implement the 2) Set the cache control values on your server so that it doesn't cache anything from your app directory @peppertech

Comment: This a lot deeper topic than can be covered in a comment. Depending on what you are using for a server, I would do a Google search for that server and cache control.  For Apache, you find something like this: http://metaskills.net/2006/02/19/how-to-control-browser-caching-with-apache-2/

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome: if you open the Developer Tools (`F12`), on the `Network` tab you can check the `Disable cache` checkbox, which turns off caching, while the DevTools is open.

With Firefox: if you open the Developer Tools (`F12`), click the cogwheel icon ("Toolbox Options"), then in the "Advanced Settings" section, check the `Disable Cache (when toolbox is open)` checkbox.

Now there will be no caching in the browser. Might slow down stuff seriously...